# ECMAScript系言語において`new Date()`の規定時間は何時ですか？

Tags: javascript

`new Date(1991, 1, 1)`を`console.log`で表示させてみますと、`"1991-01-31T15:00:00.000Z"`という出力になります。気になっているのは`15:`です。日本は確か、UTCとの9時間の差があるのすが、`15`時と論理が繋がりません。何故規定時間は午前零時ではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new Date(1991, 1, 1)` を実行した場合、実行環境のローカル時間の1991年2月1日00:00を表現するオブジェクトになります。ローカル時間が日本標準時なら、**UTC表現(`Z`)では9時間引いて前日の15:00**になります。

Comment: こちら [Date() コンストラクター](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) のページを紹介して2つ目のパラメータは月そのものではなく`0から始まるmonthIndex`だと追記すれば、より明確になると思われます。

Comment: ご回答に感謝致します。なるほど、加わるのではなく、引かれますから９時になりますね。